# Xcode error "Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ask: No such file or directory" keeps popping up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The error

> /Users/shaanyboy99/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ask_It-bnyfetjgdvoiqjaqrbyzczpmtcgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ask:
>   No such file or directory

keeps popping up. After trying numerous solutions i cant figure out the answer that works. Please help to find a solution.

Comment: Just clean your project and run it

Comment: tried that several times didnt work. Also tried deleting the Derived Data then building also didnt work.

Comment: same error face while you deleting the derived data ?

Comment: yes whenever i delete it, it automatically pops up again

Comment: did you find the answer?